# Java- Persist cannot insert to SQL table

Tags: java, jsp

I want to insert to my table in MYSQL after I fire a button like below in a JSP page:

```
<%="http://localhost:8080/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?count=1&f0="+nd.getNodeid()%>
<% 
  NodeFacade k= new NodeFacade();
  k.insert_url(nd.getNodeid(), 
               "http://localhost:8080/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?count=1&f0=" 
                             + nd.getNodeid());
%>
```

The function of this is in NodeFacade.java:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBContext;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Stateless
public class NodeFacade implements NodeFacadeLocal, NodeFacadeRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName ="PantonPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private EJBContext ejbContext;
    @EJB
    KeyGenFacadeLocal keyGenFacade;
    @EJB
    UserFacadeLocal userFacade;

    @EJB
     NodeFacadeLocal UrlLink ;
    /**
     * message
     */
    String msg = "";

    /**
     * Return messages(if any) after invoking a bean function
     * @return (String)
     */
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a node { Nodedesc, Nodegid, Nodegdt } must be set. Attributes
     * are added from the attribute map Node.attrMap if they are set.
     *
     * @param n
     * @return
     * Node with identifier {ID, DT} set on success, null on error
     *
     */
    public Node create(Node n) {
        try {

            if (n.getNodedesc() == null || n.getNodegid().longValue() == 0) {
                throw new Exception("Either description, or graph space is not set. Aborting...");
            }

            // allocate a unique identifer value for the node
            long id = keyGenFacade.generate("NODE");
            if (id == -1) {
                throw new Exception(keyGenFacade.getMsg());
            }

            n.setNodeid(id);
            n.setNodedt(new Date());

            // checks if the creator node is set:
            if (n.getNodeuid() == null) {
                Auser u = userFacade.get("root", false);
                if (u == null) {
                    throw new Exception(userFacade.getMsg());
                }
                n.setNodeuid(BigInteger.valueOf(u.getAuserPK().getNodeid()));
            }

            // persist the node into the db first
            em.persist(n);

            // add in the attributes for the node
            if (n.get_attrs() != null) {

                if (add_attr(n.getNodeid(),
                        n.get_attrs()) == -1) {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to add attributes");
                }

            }

            // adds an audit trail
            if (add_hist(n.getNodeid(),
                    NodeHist.NEW,
                    "Object (" + n.getNodetype() + ") created.",
                    n.getNodeuid().longValue()) == -1) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to add log");
            }

            return n;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            ejbContext.setRollbackOnly();

            msg = CoreUtil.wrapMsg(CoreUtil.FUNC_ERROR,
                    this.getClass().getName(), "create", e.getMessage());

            return null;
        }

    }

    public  void insert_url(long nodeid,String url){
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO urllink (NODEID, URL) VALUES (" 
                              + nodeid + ", '" + url + "')";
            em.persist(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

There is no error but it is not showing in my table in db. Did i do anything wrong?

Tried debugging it and it can pass the values correctly to the function but in the `em`, it says null.

EDIT:

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PantonPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/PANTON9</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Apasswd</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Audel</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Augroup</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Auser</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Graph</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Locktbl</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Logging</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Modlattr</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Module</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Nhist</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Node</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Nodeattr</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Nodelink</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.UrlLink</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Seqtbl</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Uwidget</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Widget</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Form.Frxcontainer</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Form.Frxebinary</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Form.Frxelement</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Form.Frxeoptions</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Converr</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Convqueue</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Filesec</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Filext</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Filter</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Fmedia</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Foldersec</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Fverinfo</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Imageinfo</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Pdfinfo</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Pindex</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Referencelink</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Stcknote</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Swfinfo</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Windex</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Iprxntfevent</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfevent</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfobj</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfqlog</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfqueue</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfug</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxattch</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxattchsec</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxendrule</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxlink</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxlog</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxmark</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxprocess</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxrule</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxrulestation</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxstation</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxtask</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxattch</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxendrule</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxlink</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxlog</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxmark</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxprocess</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxrule</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxrulestation</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxstation</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxtask</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxaction</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxattch</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxendrule</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxendstatus</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxevent</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxexception</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxlink</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxprocess</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxrule</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxrulestation</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxstation</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxversion</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxattchsec</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxattchsec</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxattchsec</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxfrx</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.PrxfrxPK</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxfrxstn</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxfrxstnelm</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.PrxfrxstnelmPK</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Iprxntfevent</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfevent</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfobj</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfqlog</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfqueue</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Notify.Ntfug</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Fmpolicy</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxapprvlist</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxdlist</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxdlistelem</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Prxdoccon</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Fmediainfo</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Hprxremarks</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Iprxremarks</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Tmpfmpolicy</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Workflow.Mprxstation</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Erequest</class>
    <class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.Ereqdetail</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: can you please share NodeFacade.java full code?

Comment: Ok i edited my post. I did not include everything since there are more than 50 functions in it, only include the relevants

Comment: just wanted to check how you have initialized em object?it might be entitymanager right?

Comment: Yes, i edited my post, you can see

Comment: Maybe the transaction is rolling back. REALLY important, though : Since you're now learning how to run SQL from a web site, it's time to learn of the dangers of SQL injection, and get into the habit of averting those right from the start  (your code is wide open to that attack).  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: Wait, how do I fix this? Does that mean my code is fine?

Comment: in persistence.xml are you using JTA transaction type? if not then change it to JTA.

Comment: i edited my post to include the persistence xml

Comment: It appears i am using JTA

Comment: @PersistenceContext(unitName ="PantonWorkflowPU")
    private EntityManager em;  use this as you have define wrong unitName as per persistence.xml file

Comment: I have another persistence xml which is pointing to PANTONPU

Comment: can you please share the right one?

Comment: Edited it ,it's correct now

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Pls help, i am stuck in this problem for days

Answer (score 1):

Can you please create entityManager object like below in your code.

```
EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PantonPU");//
EntityManager em = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: Please try with this and just let me know

Comment: create anywhere in your class before calling em.persist, this should be initialized before inserting into database.

Comment: But in my other functions, i also use `em.persist` and those functions have no issue inserting to db.

Comment: Well I added that and it doesn't even allow me to login now to my application.

Comment: okie, let me check but if your are saying that it's working for other function then i have to check once again maybe we are missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190275/discussion-between-daredevil-and-gauravrai1512).

Comment: can't access the chat as m in office, also wanted to highlight another point have you included entity class of urllink in your persistence.xml file? yes y have included just checked.

Comment: yeah i did if you check the code: `<class>com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.UrlLink</class>`

Comment: My table name is urllink and am trying to use persist directly to insert to table